# Removing hawthorn sap from cars

Tags: sap, honeydew

This came up in conversation yesterday at dinner, so I don't have specific details.  It seems in our area at least one of the hawthorns dip sap (probably more specifically honeydew) onto cars.  Folks were saying that it very difficult to get off of the cars that are parked under the trees.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Not really a gardening question, but hey, its vaguely related! Hand sanitiser used neat is the best, doesn't damage your paintwork, probably requires a bit of elbow grease if the sap's been there a while, Youtube video here  (it's not the only one that ends up recommending hand sanitiser though but its one of the more hip ones) https://youtu.be/Ri-Hi_3QrHE